# Jupyter notebook and vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I create new ec2 for jupyter server and i'm running jupyter lab with back-ground so i can access jupyter lab in browser.
However, i want to edit my ipynb file in vscode but in vscode i can connect jupyter server but i can't see directories or read files in ec2. I tried over and over to connect the server and see the directories. The only solution I got was remote ssh. however, Remote-shh is not a good way for jobs in ec2

[image: error screenshot]

Is anybody can give me an answer?

I can only see the connection with vscode and i cannot see any files plz help me

Answer (score 1):

remote ssh is the standard approach. you would need to SSH to your EC2 from vscode, then you can browse and run notebooks.

- In vscode, go to extensions and install "Remote - SSH" & "Remote - SSH: Editing Configuration Files"
- Open command palette (cmd/ctrl + shift + P) and type "show remote explorer"
- Add new ssh target by editing `~/.ssh/config`. should look like:

```
Host SOME-NAME
HostName YOUR-EC2-PUBLIC-IP
User YOUR-EC2-USER
IdentityFile PATH-TO-EC2-PEM-FILE
```

you can connect to your EC2 through vscode. you can then open .ipynb files (assuming you have required extensions. e.g: jupyter, IPython kernel) as well as having files explorer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however if i use remote ssh  the props of jupyter will be meaningless. So i want to conncet from vscode to jupyter lab only using url with token. Can you answer this question again?

Comment: vscode supports ipynb (notebooks), you will need to install ipykernel. if you still insist on using jupyter lab/notebook, you can; once you connected to the ec2 via ssh via vscode, open a terminal in vscode and run jupyter lab.

Answer (score 0):

this question is old, but still worth answering it. to edit your files in remote VSCode:

- in remote connected vscode go to terminal > new terminal, this will open an "ec2 instance" terminal.
- while there, cd to the folder you want to work on it.
- call the command "code ." this will open all the files in that folder, and you can edit or run them.